# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Last Name: You must enter a valid value: [LastName]

Tags: error-messages, shield-encryption

One of our integrations attempted to insert a `Contact` record with a value for `LastName = ?????` (yes - five question marks).

SFDC failed the insert (before any trigger executed) with:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Last Name: You must enter a valid value: [LastName]
```

I duplicated the error by entering a Contact into the UI with LastName = `?????`

LastNames of `?`, `??`, `???`, `????`, `??????` and `???????` pass, only LastNames with five question marks fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by that classic (and highly relevant) 60's garage rock song *[96 Tears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/96_Tears)* by `? and the Mysterians`, here is how I figured it out:

- I went to a Dev Edition I had laying around and tried entering a Contact with `Lastname = ?????`. This passed, no problem
- So, what was different between a Dev Edition and our Prod/sandbox world? (*remember, the error occurs before any triggers or before save flows execute). Per the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), the error occurs at Step 2*

And .... the difference was that in our PROD/sandbox world ....

- `Contact.Name` has Shield Platform Encryption enabled (Deterministic - Case Insensitive)

[image]

- I went back to the Dev Edition, enabled encryption on this field and reproduced the issue.

As an experiment, I did some other variations with a value of `?????`:

| Field | Encryption type | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Account.Name | Deterministic - Case Insensitive | Fails |
| Account.Name | Deterministic - Case Sensitive | Fails |
| Contact.Name | Probabilistic | Fails |

Assuming you need encryption on Contact.Lastname (and probably, any text field) and you get inputs of five question marks, there is no workaround.  *96 Tears* indeed.

Comment: This is a nice find.

Comment: Gosh... I love going down the rabbit hole, but this is pretty deep!

Comment: That's an impressive find.  Nicely done!